# "Customizing Consensus Mechanism in Substrate: Creating a New Block from Records via HTTP Request"

Tags: consensus

I'm working on developing a blockchain using Substrate, and I intend to customize the consensus mechanism. Specifically, I'm interested in enabling a node or a group of nodes to create a new block from specific records sent through HTTP requests. Could anyone in the community provide me with a practical example of how to implement this customization of the consensus mechanism in Substrate?

I would like to understand how to integrate the reception of records through HTTP requests and use this information for block creation. Is there any specific module I should modify or create to achieve this? Are there any special considerations I should be aware of when working on this customization?

I appreciate any guidance, code examples, or resources that can help me move forward with this project. Thank you in advance for your valuable contribution!

Best regards,